# Comunicación entre componentes

Tags: angular, servicio, component

En mi aplicación angular tengo mi componente principal app.component y luego tengo otros componentes. uno de ellos es user-notification.component. El app.component se carga primero y luego todos los demás. El problema es que en mi componente user-notification recibo los mensajes desde el backend. los mensajes tienen un valor is_read que esta en null, hasta que el mensaje se abre , entones se actualiza el valor a true. El problema es que en el componente app.componet tengo un span :
<span *ngIf="notReadMessages" class="badge_notification">

Como veis este depende de la variable  notReadMessages. El problema es que no consigo que se actualice la variable en app.component. Desde el user-notification al servicio llega, pero desde el servicio al app.component no consigo que se actualice.

El app.component es el componente principal (Padre) y se carga el primero, no sé si tendrá algo que ver. Pero es importante que se actualice la variable en tiempo real, para mantener el span

En mi componente user-notification tengo el siguiente método:

```
  updateMessageStatusIsRead(response) {
    if(response.is_read == null){
      console.log('is not read ',response.is_read);
      this.notReadMessages = true;
      console.log(this.notReadMessages);
      this._messagesService.messageReadStatus(true);
    } else {
      this.notReadMessages = false;
      console.log('is read ',response.is_read);
      console.log(this.notReadMessages);
      this._messagesService.messageReadStatus(false);
    }
  }
```

este es mi servicio

```
  private notReadMessagesSubject = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
  public notReadMessages$ = this.notReadMessagesSubject.asObservable();


  messageReadStatus(status: boolean) {
    console.log(status);
    this.notReadMessagesSubject.next(status);
  }
```

y este es app.component

```
    this.subscription = this._messagesService.notReadMessages$.subscribe(status => {
      this.notReadMessages = status;
      console.log(this.notReadMessages);
    });
```

Necesito ayuda. o si alguien tiene algún método distinto , lo agradecería.

**El problema es que desde el user-notification al servicio llega , pero en el app.component no hace nada**

Además, he probado los métodos BehaviorSubject o Subject. y nada

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: hola. desde el user-notification al servicio llega , pero en el app.component no hace nada

Comment: Haber, la subscripción en `app.component`, donde esta? Si te esta mostrando el `console.log` o tampoco hace nada? Puede ser un problema del `ng serve`, en ocasiones no refleja los cambios y hay que pararlo completamente.

Comment: hola. he probado poner la subscripción tanto en el onInit como en el constructor, el console.log se muestra cuando se carga la pagina con el valor de la variable , pero luego cuando actualizo la variable en el otro componente ya no hace nada.

Answer (score 0):

yo hice algo parecido en un sistema que estoy desarrollando, en tu servicio agrega una función que regrese un Observable:

```
getMessageReadStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.notReadMessages$;
}
```

Y en tu componente desde tu `ngOnInit` mandas a llamar esta función dentro de tu servicio:

```
this.subscription = this._messagesService.getMessageReadStatus().subscribe(status => {
  this.notReadMessages = status;
  console.log(this.notReadMessages);
});
```